# I can't figure out why i'm getting duplicate index per matching sublist

Tags: python, numpy

What im trying to do is take the fastest route to mark each and every index of a sublist inside a specific superlist.

```
import numpy as np

l1 = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b']]
l2 = ['a', 'b']
a = np.array(l1)
b = np.array(l2)

x = np.where(a == b)[0]
print(x)
```

output:

```
[0 0 2 2 3 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

because you are getting the first element only of the output `[0]`, `a` is 2D array and the output have 2 indices "for row and column position"

```
import numpy as np

l1 = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b']]
l2 = ['a', 'b']
a = np.array(l1)
b = np.array(l2)

x,y = np.where(a == b)
a[x,y]
array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], dtype='<U1')
```

if you wish to compare them array wise you should loop through `a`

```
x = np.where([np.array_equal(i,b) for i in a])[0]
x
array([0, 2, 3], dtype=int64)
```